# TLS/SSL with Wildfly 16.0.0.Final and ejb client fails with org.xnio.http.UpgradeFailedException: Invalid response code 200

Tags: java, ssl, jboss, ejb, wildfly

I have setup an EJB client that can connect successfuly to `remote+http://localhost:8080` without SSL/TLS.

Now I have created a truststore and keystore and followed the instructions in the Wildfly documentation [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/WildFly+Elytron+Security#WildFlyElytronSecurity-EnableOnewaySSL%2FTLSforApplications) to setup SSL/TLS.

My `wildfly-config.xml` contains the following:

```
<authentication-client xmlns="urn:elytron:1.0">
    <authentication-rules>
        <rule use-configuration="default-config"/>
    </authentication-rules>
    <authentication-configurations>
        <configuration name="default-config">
            <set-user-name name="${user}"/>
            <credentials>
                <clear-password password="${password}"/>
            </credentials>
            <sasl-mechanism-selector selector="#ALL" />
            <providers>
                <use-service-loader />
            </providers>
        </configuration>
    </authentication-configurations>

    <key-stores>
        <key-store name="im-keystore" type="JKS">
            <file name="client.truststore"/>
            <key-store-clear-password password="xxx"/>
        </key-store>
    </key-stores>

    <ssl-contexts>
        <ssl-context name="im-ssl-context">
            <trust-store key-store-name="im-keystore"/>
            <protocol names="TLSv1.2"/>
        </ssl-context>
    </ssl-contexts>

    <ssl-context-rules>
        <rule use-ssl-context="im-ssl-context"/>
    </ssl-context-rules>
</authentication-client>
```

The server is configured as follows:

```
<tls>
    <key-stores>
        <key-store name="httpsKS">
            <credential-reference clear-text="xxx"/>
            <implementation type="JKS"/>
            <file path="server.keystore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
        </key-store>
    </key-stores>
    <key-managers>
        <key-manager name="httpsKM" key-store="httpsKS">
            <credential-reference clear-text="xxx"/>
        </key-manager>
    </key-managers>
    <server-ssl-contexts>
        <server-ssl-context name="httpsSSC" protocols="TLSv1.2" key-manager="httpsKM"/>
    </server-ssl-contexts>
</tls>
```

and

```
<https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" ssl-context="httpsSSC" enable-http2="true"/>
```

Now the ejb client throws the following exception when connecting to `remote+https://localhost:8443`:

```
LOG 2019-06-13T12:12:56Z [XNIO-1 task-1] TRACE org.jboss.remoting.endpoint - Registered exception result
org.xnio.http.UpgradeFailedException: Invalid response code 200
    at org.xnio.http.HttpUpgrade$HttpUpgradeState$UpgradeResultListener.handleEvent(HttpUpgrade.java:471) ~[xnio-api-3.6.5.Final.jar:3.6.5.Final]
    at org.xnio.http.HttpUpgrade$HttpUpgradeState$UpgradeResultListener.handleEvent(HttpUpgrade.java:400) ~[xnio-api-3.6.5.Final.jar:3.6.5.Final]
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92) ~[xnio-api-3.6.5.Final.jar:3.6.5.Final]
    at org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66) ~[xnio-api-3.6.5.Final.jar:3.6.5.Final]
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:89) ~[xnio-nio-3.6.5.Final.jar:3.6.5.Final]
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:591) ~[xnio-nio-3.6.5.Final.jar:3.6.5.Final]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It turned out, that an additional remoting connector was missing that points with `connector-ref` to the `https-listener` defined in the `undertow` subsection:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:4.0">
  <http-connector name="http-remoting-connector" connector-ref="default" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
  <http-connector name="https-remoting-connector" connector-ref="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
</subsystem>
```